# Is it legal to webscrape data from instagram?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, python-3.7

My code is hosted on given link if it needs to be checked.
Also the data scrape is not used for any research purposes or business related.
The code is just for learning Web scraping.
https://github.com/Devanshchowdhury2212/Instagram-Web-scraping-

Comment: This is off-topic for this site as not a programming question. Scraping websites is usually illegal and checkable within T&Cs and robots.txt. However, there has been a ruling in the US ~2yrs ago in favour of a company scraping publicly available linkedin data. I'd argue the challenge is probably more technical than legal though.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/) **Terms of Use**

- You can't attempt to create accounts or access or collect information in unauthorized ways.

  - This includes creating accounts or collecting information in an automated way without our express permission.

**Conclusion**: Avoid web scraping *Instagram*.